# How to get selection field value in RML

Tags: report, odoo, rml

I have a selection field and I want to print the selected value but I got the key.

*Python code*:

```
'transport': fields.selection([('plain','Plain'),
                               ('train','Train'),
                               ('taxi','Taxi'),
                               ('bus','Bus'), 
                               ('sv','Service vehicle')],'Means of transport'),
```

*RML:*

```
[[ o.transport or '']]
```

When I select `Plain` the printed value is `plain`.

How to get `Plain` in the printed report instead of `plain`?

Answer (score 0):

We may achieve in two ways.

1. Direct condition on .rml and
2. Using function

**Direct condition on .rml**

For example:

```
[[ o.transport == 'avion' and 'Avion' or o.transport == 'train' and 'Train' ]]
```

**Using function**

We need to add function on report .py file

```
def _get_value_from_selection_field(self, model, field, value):

    selection = self.pool.get(model)._columns.get(field).selection

    res = ''

    for v in selection:

        if v[0] == value:

            res = v[1]

        break

    return res
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the RML code but nothing was printed.